# Approving edits for those with over 2k points

Tags: support

I know that suggested edits from users with less than 2k have to be approved by multiple people.

Can some one please confirm if this is the case or not if you have over 2k.

Bad spelling bugs me (and I'm guilty of it) so if I see an error, I like to fix it, even if it's a minor change. Am I now creating more work for other users who are having to approve  my edits or does my reputation allow the change to just be saved immediately?

Comment: >2k folks don't go through peer reviews

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you reach 2000 reputation you can edit posts without having them peer reviewed.

From the [Privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges/edit) page:

> That means once you've generated enough reputation, we trust you to edit anything in the system without it going through the peer review system.

Comment: Thank you again Oliver. Sorry, I did look in the Help section, but couldn't see it under reputation.